# How to specify a file path for ftp in xml

Tags: asp.net, xml

How to specify a file path of a server to access it's directory in xml file.

This I can specify in Local Server.

```
<file value="C:\\Log\LogFile.txt"/>
```

How to specify the same in another server which I'm accessing it through ftp..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I directly added the physical path to the xml file when uploading. If I give, ftp path, it is not working... Then, I found the physical path and I applied the physical path.

Anyway Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
ftp://hostname/path/to/file.txt
```

or with authentication

```
ftp://username:password@hostname/path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: No.. It is showing error... It is not taking the path in that way.. If we use, ftp directly, then how it will get the username and password? Then, there will be no security know??